# Bootstrap datetimepicker css not working properly even if used latest api

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Sorry if its repeated but i cannot found solution. So ask on stackoverflow.
[image]

You can check my problem in image and also see that all required files are included. Just check it and help to fix it.

Thanks in advance.
Below is my code:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-sm-3" >Set Date : </label>
  <div class="col-sm-8">
    <input type="text" id="datetimepicker" class="form-control datetimepicker" name="date_add_custom" placeholder="Set Date" value=""  autocomplete="off"/>
  </div>
</div>

    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/stylesheet.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/moment.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrapValidator.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
        // format:'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm',
        format:'MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm',  //HH = 24 hours
        pickTime: true,
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Please, post your completed code or provide a demo. Nobody can solve your problem by image.

Comment: Can you show where you are loading jQuery too?

Comment: Also, change your code to use the correct selector, you need to pick by id, not class here: `$('#datetimepicker').... `

Comment: Which datetimepicker is it? There are more than one that are go around with the name *Bootstrap datepicker*.

Comment: You should put your call to datepicker inside a domready function.

Comment: @Dontfeedthecode already tried that, but can't succeed. This is very popular twitter bootstrap 3 .

Comment: @OmInfowaveDevelopers put a jsfiddle up somewhere with your code.